# How can I achieve better throughput for a large migration to DynamoDB?

Tags: java, performance, amazon-dynamodb

I have been running a test for a large data migration to dynamo that we intend to do in our prod account this summer.  I ran a test to batch write about 3.2 billion documents to our dynamo table, which has a hash and range keys and two partial indexes.  Each document is small, less than 1k.  While we succeeded in getting the items written in about 3 days, we were disappointed with the Dynamo performance we experienced and are looking for suggestions on how we might improve things.

In order to do this migration, we are using 2 ec2 instances (c4.8xlarges).  Each runs up to 10 processes of our migration program; we've split the work among the processes by some internal parameters and know that some processes will run longer than others.  Each process queries our RDS database for 100,000 records. We then split these into partitions of 25 each and use a threadpool of 10 threads to call the DynamoDB java SDK's batchSave() method.  Each call to batchSave() is sending only 25 documents that are less than 1k each, so we expect each to only make a single HTTP call out to AWS.  This means that at any given time, we can have as many as 100 threads on a server each making calls to batchSave with 25 records.   Our RDS instance handled the load of queries to it just fine during this time, and our 2 EC2 instances did as well.  On the ec2 side, we did not max out our cpu, memory, or network in or network out.  Our writes are not grouped by hash key, as we know that can be known to slow down dynamo writes.  In general, in a group of 100,000 records, they are split across 88,000 different hash keys.  I created the dynamo table initially with 30,000 write throughput, but configured up to 40,000 write throughput at one point during the test, so our understanding is that there are at least 40 partitions on the dynamo side to handle this.

We saw very variable responses times in our calls to batchSave() to dynamo throughout this period. For one span of 20 minutes while I was running 100 threads per ec2 instance, the average time was 0.636 seconds, but the median was only 0.374, so we've got a lot of calls taking more than a second.    I'd expect to see much more consistency in the time it takes to make these calls from an EC2 instance to dynamo.  Our dynamo table seems to have plenty of throughput configured, and the EC2 instance is below 10% CPU, and the network in and out look healthy, but are not close to be maxed out.  The CloudWatch graphs in the console (which are fairly terrible...) didn't show any throttling of write requests.

After I took these sample times, some of our processes finished their work, so we were running less threads on our ec2 instances.  When that happened, we saw dramatically improved response times in our calls to dynamo.  e.g. when we were running 40 threads instead of 100 on the ec2 instance, each  making calls to batchSave, the response times improved more than 5x.  However, we did NOT see improved write throughput even with the increased better response times.  It seems that no matter what we configured our write throughput to be, we never really saw the actual throughput exceed 15,000.

We'd like some advice on how best to achieve better performance on a Dynamo migration like this.  Our production migration this summer will be time-sensitive, of course, and by then, we'll be looking to migrate about 4 billion records.  Does anyone have any advice on how we can achieve an overall higher throughput rate?  If we're willing to pay for 30,000 units of write throughput for our main index during the migration, how can we actually achieve performance close to that?

Comment: Use the S3 import functionality... We've just done this from OpenSearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One component of BatchWrite latency is the Put request that takes the longest in the Batch. Considering that you have to loop over the List of DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch until it is empty, you might not be making progress fast enough. Consider running multiple parallel [DynamoDBMapper.save()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#save%28T%29) calls instead of batchSave so that you can make progress independently for each item you write.

Again, Cloudwatch metrics are 1 minute metrics so you may have peaks of consumption and throttling that are masked by the 1 minute window. This is compounded by the fact that the SDK, by default, will retry throttled calls [10 times](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/e925ba8defbb04a1c5f8af7860d4501186bbfeb7/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/retry/PredefinedRetryPolicies.java#L112) before exposing the ProvisionedThroughputExceededException to the client, making it difficult to pinpoint when and where the actual throttling is happening. To improve your understanding, try reducing the number of SDK retries, request ConsumedCapacity=TOTAL, self-throttle your writes using Guava RateLimiter as is described in the [rate-limited scan blog post](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3VAYQIZ3Q0ZVW/Rate-Limited-Scans-in-Amazon-DynamoDB), and log throttled primary keys to see if any patterns emerge.

Finally, the number of partitions of a table is not only driven by the amount of read and write capacity units you provision on your table. It is also driven by the amount of data you store in your table. Generally, a partition stores up to 10GB of data and then will split. So, if you just write to your table without deleting old entries, the number of partitions in your table will grow without bound. This causes IOPS starvation - even if you provision 40000 WCU/s, if you already have 80 partitions due to the amount of data, the 40k WCU will be distributed among 80 partitions for an average of 500 WCU per partition. To control the amount of stale data in your table, you can have a rate-limited cleanup process that scans and removes old entries, or use [rolling time-series tables](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/building-applications-with-dynamodb) (slides 84-95) and delete/migrate entire tables of data as they become less relevant. Rolling time-series tables is less expensive than rate-limited cleanup as you do not consume WCU with a DeleteTable operation, while you consume at least 1 WCU for each DeleteItem call.